# super.onbackpressed() in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to click on the image to go to the last activity[image]

error when calling the standard method

Comment: Please post the actual code instead of a screenshot

Comment: also please post the actual error instead of "error when calling the standard method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most easiest way but **`not`** a safe and should `not` be a recommended one since we don't know what context could be here,  but if it's just for testing activity switching, this might suffice.

```
val context = LocalContext.current

     ...
     ...

.clickable {
     (context as <Your Activity>).finish() // cast context to what ever the name of your Activity is
}
```

So consider the 2 approaches below.

Either you create a deep nest of passing your activity instance like this (assuming your `Image` is within this composable scope)

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(activity: Activity) { // activity parameter

    ...
    ...
    
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            activity.finish() // use it here
        }
    )
}
```

or you can utilize `CompositionLocalProvider`, setting your activity instance within the scope of the contained composable

```
val LocalActivity = staticCompositionLocalOf<ComponentActivity> {
    error("LocalActivity is not present")
}

class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalActivity provides this@MyActivity) {
                MyAppTheme {
                    MyComposable()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then using it like this,

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {

    ...
    ...

    val myActivityInstance = LocalActivity.current

    Image(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
            myActivityInstance.finish()
        }
    )
}
```