# Best practice to implement startActivity using ViewModel in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, start-activity

For example, I have this simple Composable function

```
@Composable
fun TextExample(model: SomeViewModel = viewModel()) {
    TextButton(onClick = { model.onClick() }) {
        Text(text = "Test")
    }
}
```

The SomeViewModel:

```
class SomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _text = mutableStateOf("Test")
    val text: String
        get() = _text.value

    fun onClick() {
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            // TODO: need to start some activity
        } else {
            _text.value = ""
        }
    }
}
```

I clicking this Button and then the model must to handle this click. In some cases I need to start another activity. What is right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might better approach to this but you can consider mine.

Id suggest first to create a data structure for "one time events" with a `Sealed Class` like this

```
sealed class Events {
    object ToActivityA: Events()
    object ToActivityB: Events()
    data class ToastMessage(val message: String): Events()
}
```

Declare a `SharedFlow` in your ViewModel  that will emit these events

```
private val _events = MutableSharedFlow<Events>()
val events: SharedFlow<Events> = _events
```

and in your case, emit an event from your onClick viewmodel function like this

```
fun onClick() {
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _events.emit(Events.ToActivityA) // or ToActivityB, or for a Toast 
        }
    } else {
        _text.value = ""
    }
}
```

Now in your composable, just observe it in a `LaunchedEffect` like this

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit) {
        viewModel.events.collectLatest {
            when (it) {
                Events.ToActivityA -> {
                    // to activity A
                }
                Events.ToActivityB -> {
                    // to activity B
                }
                is Events.ToastMessage -> {
                    // show toast message
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If you don't have something prepared yet for calling startActivity, I'd suggest visiting this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74424253/super-onbackpressed-in-jetpack-compose/74427398#74427398) as a reference.

Comment: How do you think, this solution may to extend on alert dialogs? Now I'm using this way:
private val _needShowAppVersionIsOutOfDateDialog = mutableStateOf(false)
    val needShowAppVersionIsOutOfDateDialog: Boolean
        get() = _needShowAppVersionIsOutOfDateDialog.value

    fun closeNeedShowAppVersionIsOutOfDateDialog() {
        _needShowAppVersionIsOutOfDateDialog.value = false
    }

Comment: I think yes, you can utilize the approach in my answer for dialogs as well